# K-Theory, how to start

Tags: book-recommendation, k-theory

This semester I'm studing courses about representation theory, ring theory, algebraic topology and homological algebra, and this huge mix between algebra and topology made my think about other ways to learn topology by the algebra. I've searched some subfields or close fields to algebraic topology and I found thing or two about fields called "algebraic K-teory" and "topological K-theory", which is a use to ring theory in topology (if I'm correct).

I've tried to read about this field but I didnt find any helpful articles or books.

My question is: What do I need to know (which fields at mathematics) before studying K-theory? and which books are recommended?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I used the [K-book](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html) by Weibel when I needed to learn algebraic K-theory. I have no idea how it compares to other Introductory texts.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you! I will try to read